# How can I prevent grease pencil transparency?

Tags: animation, transparency, layers, grease-pencil

I'm basically doing a scene where there are dancing jeans walking by themselves( Don't Ask!lol) I want a situation whereby as it is moving one leg will overlap the other.[image: at frame 0]

As I tried doing this, it became transparent when I tried to do so
[image: at frame 10]
It's all in the same layer, as using different layers for the same object would be tasking. I was wondering if there is a way for it no to be transparent so that the leg will cover the other.